# Fastapi и Sqlalchemy как передать сессию

Tags: sqlalchemy, dependency-injection, fastapi

У меня есть асинхронная функция, которая возвращает async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession]. Она вызывается при старте приложения(@app.on_event("startup")). Эту сессию я хочу использовать в своих эндпоинтах. Как ее передать туда?